# NodeJS Dynamic Import Modules from another module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

```
ModuleA
    src
        index.js
        modules
            utility.js


ModuleB
    src
        framework
            activities
                activity.js
```

ModuleA is my main "runnable" module.
ModuleB is like a framework library or SDK that Module A depends on.

The activity.js in ModuleB has to dynamically invoke a module in ModuleA.

```
const module = await import(await import.meta.resolve(`${moduleName}`, import.meta.url));
await module.execute(...);
```

The problem I have is the moduleName string that Module B expects is looking ugly.

```
"../../../../ModuleA/src/modules/utility.js"
```

I'm imagining there must be a better way to express this path.

I simply want to be able to pass this:

```
"modules/utility.js"
```

Everything upto ModuleA/src must be made implicit and made aware to ModuleB somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this package can help in simplifying dynamic imports
https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias